# How to Use Navigation Push Asycn in Master Detail Page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to make my xamarin forms app when the menu item is clicked instead change the master detail page it go to another page and shows navigation bar with back button in the top. but i got confused in how to change the on menu item selected, here is my onmenuitemSelected

```
private void OnMenuItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{

        var item = (DrawerItem)e.SelectedItem;
        Type page = item.TargetType;

        //Navigation.PushAsync((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));
        //new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));

        Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));
       IsPresented = false;
    }
```

As you can see in the comment tag i already try to do Navigation.Push async and tried New NavigationPage only without Detail but when im click the menu item its do nothing, so what code should i write to do that. and so here what i try to do[image: the right navigation]
and this is what i get when i click the item in the masterdetail page
[image]

what code should i write to able do that ?

Comment: Are you mean you want hide menu icon after select menuitem?

Comment: hmm no what i want is like create navigation page stack, instead changing the Detail page. as you can see my code is    "Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));" and its change the Detail page what i want is create new navigation page so when i press the back button its go back to Detail page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nevermind i already found the solution to my problem, here if you have same problem like me

```
private void OnMenuItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
var item = (MasterPageItem)e.SelectedItem;
Type page = item.TargetType;
// Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));
Detail.Navigation.PushAsync((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));
IsPresented = false;
}
```